# How to inject custom code into the every instantiation of a built-in class in Swift?

Tags: swift, uikit

I need to execute some code in the instantiation of every `UILabel` in my application. **For debug/research purposes.**

So, I would like to do something like this:

```swift
// yep, it is not possible to override in an extension
extension UILabel {
    override init(...) { // what about arguments? overloading? no idea
        super.init(...)
        print("UILabel was created")
    }
}
```

or like this:

```swift
// yep, it is not a valid syntax
#define UILabel MyLabel

class MyLabel : UILabel {
    override init(...) { // what about arguments? overloading? no idea
        super.init(...)
        print("UILabel was created")
    }
}
```

Both of the examples above are not a working Swift code, but I hope there is some correct solution to *inject my code* into the instantiation of every `UILabel`.

It does not have to be a clean solution. The code will never leave my local debug build, so any dirty hacks are totally acceptable as long as they do the job.

Thanks.

Comment: read about `method swizzling`, may be useful

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to inject code into every instantiation of UILabel without creating a custom class.

Based on your approach, I would create a class like this and use it for all UILabel

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("UILabel was created")
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

let myLabel: MyLabel = {
    let label = MyLabel()
    label.text = "123"
    return label
}()
```

or use it as an extension

```
extension UILabel {
    func initiate() {
        print("UILabel was created")
    }
}

let myLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.initiate()
    label.text = "123"
    return label
}()
```

Comment: Yes, I know about this option. Unfortunately my current project is too large and is divided into several repos, so it is difficult to edit all the places where UILabel is created.